# Why can't view the my project in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp, localhost, host

I am struck Here, create one project, project name is medicals.

I am Using xampp. i wrote in http.conf like.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/medicals/public"
   ServerName medicals.com

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/medicals/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And,Using Windows `path:C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` point to.

```
127.0.0.1       medicals.com
```

i have an error im my browser to access the `medicals.com`.

[image]

Where is the actual issue. i did't understand.

Thhanks in advance.

Comment: Could you check, what is the Apache version of your xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please  Confirm your port is 80, In case you use another port in xampp u can change the line `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:8080>`, the 8080 is a port number second commonly used, you change 8080  into your port,

your port number shown in xampp control pannel PFA[image]

Comment: This is not a feature of zend, all the domain are hosted in this type

Answer (score 1):

Copy following code :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName medicals.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/medicals/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/medicals/public">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

To:

```
C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And also add following line :

```
127.0.0.1 medicals.com
```

to

```
C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc
```

And also make sure your `mod_rewrite` is enabled and don't forget to restart your apache server after change.

This works for me in zf3. If it does not work in zf1 you may want to look at this.
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/project-structure.rewrite.html

Comment: @thanks, what your search for me, But it's not work for me.. why you 
 should write here httpd-vhosts.conf usally we wrote C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf. right..

Comment: Have you uncomment the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` on httpd.conf around line no 503